# Manually test smb endpoint connection on linux

Tags: linux, apache-camel, smb, jcifs

I have a small Apache Camel application that picks up files at a smb endpoint:

```
smb://domain.nl;user-name@domain.nl/my/file/location?password=Blablabla&move=${processedFolder}&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true
```

Recently we had a glitch and the process failed after moving some of the files we had lined up. Logs made it clear the files from the smb location suddenly became inaccesible.
The first thing i tried was checking if i could get to the smb endpoint, like this:

```
smbclient -L domain.nl -U user-name -d 10
```

This returned **session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE** after many debug lines.

Long story short, it turned out it was just a glitch, after rerunning camel all the files were picked up. So smbclient is not the way to check if apache camel using Samba JCIFS can access a location. But what is? Next time, how can i check manually from the linux server if a smb location is available?

I should note that the linux-version is ancient, 5.5 redhat.

camel version: 2.20.1, 
camel jcifs version: 2.18.0, 
jcifs version: 1.3.18

Comment: I would suggest handling the error that was in the logs so that Camel route notifies you.

Comment: Camel logs and notifies me correctly.

Comment: So you are handling the exception then?

Comment: @Namphibian yes, no problems there. But i want to be able to test the smb connection between the production server and the remote location prior to, in addition to, apache camel file manipulation.

Comment: Yeah I hear you. Just think about it like this. Things will fail that is going to happen so handle the fault by retrying or alerting someone. You can test for sure but a second later it can fail. So the most successful way of dealing with the problem is to handle it. If you need info on doing that let me know.